# Stop auto type at last array

Tags: javascript, arrays, erase

I'm trying to stop erasing my "auto typed text" when the last array is reached.
I've been searching so for on Google but I can't find any solution.

```js
const typedTextSpan = document.querySelector(".typed-text");
const cursorSpan = document.querySelector(".cursor");
const textArray = ["reconnaitre un talent ?", "détécter une opportunité ?"];
const typingDelay = 170;
const erasingDelay = 100;
const newTextDelay = 2000;
let textArrayIndex = 0;
let charIndex = 0;

function type() {
  if (charIndex < textArray[textArrayIndex].length) {
    if (cursorSpan.classList.contains("typing")) cursorSpan.classList.add("typing");
    typedTextSpan.textContent += textArray[textArrayIndex].charAt(charIndex);
    charIndex++;
    setTimeout(type, typingDelay);
  } else {
    cursorSpan.classList.remove("typing");
    setTimeout(erase, newTextDelay);
  }
}

function erase() {
  if (charIndex > 0) {
    if (!cursorSpan.classList.contains("typing")) cursorSpan.classList.add("typing");
    typedTextSpan.textContent = textArray[textArrayIndex].substring(0, charIndex - 1);
    charIndex--;
    setTimeout(erase, erasingDelay);
  } else {
    cursorSpan.classList.remove("typing");
    textArrayIndex++;
    if (textArrayIndex >= textArray.length) textArrayIndex = 0;
    setTimeout(type, typingDelay + 1100);
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  if (textArray.length) setTimeout(type, newTextDelay + 250);
});
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container">
  <h1>Savez-vous <span class="typed-text" id="typed-text"></span><span class="cursor" id="cursor">&nbsp;</span></h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your functions keep calling each other without any signal to stop somewhere. You already keep track of where your index currently is in the `textArray` with `textArrayIndex`. Use that to see if the end has been reached in the `else` statement of your `type` function.

```
if (textArrayIndex < textArray.length - 1) {
  setTimeout(erase, newTextDelay);
}
```

Here it checks if the current index is lower than the last index of the array. If it is, it will continue to call the `erase` function and increment `textArrayIndex` with `1` there. Otherwise when the index is not lower than the last index, meaning it's the last one, it will simply do nothing, thus breaking the loop.

```js
const typedTextSpan = document.querySelector(".typed-text");
const cursorSpan = document.querySelector(".cursor");
const textArray = ["reconnaitre un talent ?", "détécter une opportunité ?"];
const typingDelay = 170;
const erasingDelay = 100;
const newTextDelay = 2000;
let textArrayIndex = 0;
let charIndex = 0;

function type() {
  if (charIndex < textArray[textArrayIndex].length) {
    if (cursorSpan.classList.contains("typing")) cursorSpan.classList.add("typing");
    typedTextSpan.textContent += textArray[textArrayIndex].charAt(charIndex);
    charIndex++;
    setTimeout(type, typingDelay);
  } else {
    cursorSpan.classList.remove("typing");
    
    // Erase if the end has not yet been reached.
    if (textArrayIndex < textArray.length - 1) {
      setTimeout(erase, newTextDelay);
    }
  }
}

function erase() {
  if (charIndex > 0) {
    if (!cursorSpan.classList.contains("typing")) cursorSpan.classList.add("typing");
    typedTextSpan.textContent = textArray[textArrayIndex].substring(0, charIndex - 1);
    charIndex--;
    setTimeout(erase, erasingDelay);
  } else {
    cursorSpan.classList.remove("typing");
    textArrayIndex++;
    setTimeout(type, typingDelay + 1100);
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  if (textArray.length) setTimeout(type, newTextDelay + 250);
});
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container">
  <h1>Savez-vous <span class="typed-text" id="typed-text"></span><span class="cursor" id="cursor">&nbsp;</span></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey :)
thanks a lot, i was focused on the last index of the textArray lol.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the `textArrayIndex` with the `textArray` length in erase function. Please check below code for this.

```js
const typedTextSpan = document.querySelector(".typed-text");
const cursorSpan = document.querySelector(".cursor");
const textArray = ["reconnaitre un talent ?", "détécter une opportunité ?"];
const typingDelay = 170;
const erasingDelay = 100;
const newTextDelay = 2000;
let textArrayIndex = 0;
let charIndex = 0;

function type() {
  if (charIndex < textArray[textArrayIndex].length) {
    if (cursorSpan.classList.contains("typing")) cursorSpan.classList.add("typing");
    typedTextSpan.textContent += textArray[textArrayIndex].charAt(charIndex);
    charIndex++;
    setTimeout(type, typingDelay);
  } else {
    cursorSpan.classList.remove("typing");
    setTimeout(erase, newTextDelay);
  }
}

function erase() {
  // Check index
  if(textArrayIndex == textArray.length - 1) {
      // Stop Erase
      return false; 
  }
  if (charIndex > 0) {
    if (!cursorSpan.classList.contains("typing")) cursorSpan.classList.add("typing");
    typedTextSpan.textContent = textArray[textArrayIndex].substring(0, charIndex - 1);
    charIndex--;
    setTimeout(erase, erasingDelay);
  } else {
    cursorSpan.classList.remove("typing");
    textArrayIndex++;
    if (textArrayIndex >= textArray.length) textArrayIndex = 0;
    setTimeout(type, typingDelay + 1100);
  }
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  if (textArray.length) setTimeout(type, newTextDelay + 250);
});
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container">
  <h1>Savez-vous <span class="typed-text" id="typed-text"></span><span class="cursor" id="cursor">&nbsp;</span></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello,
Thank you so much.
Like i said in the previous comment, i was focused on the last index of textArray :)